# Print query result on form page

Tags: webforms, database

I'm writing a custom module to obtain an online quote.

The form has an additional button and once it is clicked, a database query runs and print a value.

```
//My code for custom button
function garden_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state,$form_id ){
if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_4208') {
$form['actions']['garden_quote']  = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Get online estimate'),
    '#submit' => array('mymodule_custom_submit'),
);
$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_validate'; 
}
}

//Custom submit handler
function mymodule_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$query = db_select('gardenvalue', 'f');
$query->fields('f', array('total_cost'))
    ->condition('meters', '2', '=');
$result = $query->execute();
dpm($result);
}
```

Once the form has been submitted dpm shows the 'meters' value as'db_condition_placeholder_0' and not number 2. What can be the reason?

Also I would like to show the $result value on a new text field once the form reloads. If we assume this new text field key is 'total_garden' how can I change its' value to $result on form reload?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
//My code for custom button
function garden_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){
    if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_4208') {
        $form['actions']['garden_quote']  = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Get online estimate'),
            '#submit' => array('garden_custom_submit'),
        );
        $form['#validate'][] = 'garden_custom_validate'; 
    }
}

//Custom submit handler
function garden_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $query = db_select('gardenvalue', 'f');
    $query->fields('f', array('total_cost'))
        ->condition('f.meters', 2, '=');
    $result = $query->execute();
    dpm($result);
}
```

You have spacing errors and identation errors, the condition is not pointing to a field in the table, and you have to dig into the results array to extract the value, as far as I know you only can print results in a form with

`drupal_set_message(t('your message', 'success');` instead of `dpm` hope this help you a little bit...